# Mobile first media queries: Is there a way to 'scope' styles (regarding visibility classes)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am developing a page using CSS3 media queries using the mobile first approach, meaning I start small and work my way up.

But now I am encountering a problem: How to deal with 'style bleeding' for visibility classes?
Let me explain what I mean – when my first media query looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 20em) {
    // Styles here
}
```

These styles don't get applied to screens smaller than 20em. This actually is no problem because the styles that are not wrapped up in a media query are basically the first media query (I hope you get what I mean).

But now I want to introduce visibility classes to hide elements for certain screen sizes. The problem is, that these styles basically get inherited. See:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 20em) {
    .hidden-first {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Any element with the class `hidden-first` gets hidden as soon as the screen is 20em wide or wider. But I only want to hide the element as long as the media query is active.

How do I do that – is there a way around resetting the style inside another media query?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a class like `hide-for-medium`and create rule for it `display:none !important;`

Take a look at the [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework and see how the do it. I guess it's the best way to deal with this situation.